# The discrete Fourier series in Peskin and Schroeder (page 285)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, path-integral, discrete

I'm working on the discrete Fourier series in Peskin (page 285)，but I have two questions.

[image]

**Question 1**:

I tried to derive Eq.(9.21):

Consider $$
f(x)=\int \frac{d^{4} k}{(2 \pi)^{4}} e^{-i k \cdot x} \tilde{f}(k)
$$
So we have \begin{align}
\phi(x_i)&=\int \frac{d^{4} k}{(2 \pi)^{4}} e^{-i k \cdot x_i} \phi(k)\\&=
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}
\sum_{n} \frac{\Delta^{4} k_n}{(2 \pi)^{4}} e^{-i k_n \cdot x_i} \phi(k_n)
\end{align}
In finite volume we have $k_n=\frac{2\pi n}{L}$,so $$\Delta^{4} k_n=\frac{(2\pi)^4}{L^4}=\frac{(2\pi)^4}{V}$$
So the Fourier transform of finite volume is
\begin{align}
\phi(x_i)&=\sum_{n} \frac{\Delta^{4} k_n}{(2 \pi)^{4}} e^{-i k_n \cdot x_i} \phi(k_n)\\&=
\sum_{n} \frac{(2\pi)^4}{(2 \pi)^{4}V} e^{-i k_n \cdot x_i} \phi(k_n)\\&=\frac{1}{V}
\sum_{n} e^{-i k_n \cdot x_i} \phi(k_n)
\end{align}
This is consistent with Eq.(9.21). However, I didnʻt use $\left|k^{\mu}\right|<\pi / \epsilon$. Where does it come from？Is my derivation wrong？

**Question 2**:

I tried to derive this equation but I have difficulties $$
\mathcal{D} \phi(x)=\prod_{k_{n}^{0}>0} d \operatorname{Re} \phi\left(k_{n}\right) d \operatorname{Im} \phi\left(k_{n}\right).
$$
Consider Eq.(9.20)
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D} \phi&=\prod_{i} d \phi\left(x_{i}\right)\\&=\prod_{i} d 
\left(\frac{1}{V} \sum_{n} e^{-i k_{n} \cdot x_{i}} \phi\left(k_{n}\right)\right)
\end{align}
I don't know how to go on. Now how do I derive this equation？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with your first question. Peskin and Schroeder are putting all of the fields in a box with volume $V = L^4$ in Euclidian Space (after Wick Rotation). This means that smallest Fourier mode the fields can have is $k^{\mu} = \frac{2\pi}{L}$. However, that box is discretized into a lattice with lattice spacing $\epsilon$. This lattice spacing brings with it a UV cutoff to all of the fields, coarse graining the fields so that the largest Fourier mode the fields can have is $k^{\mu} = \frac{\pi}{\epsilon}$. Having both a lattice spacing and a finite box means your theory have UV and IR cut offs. So the Fourier Integrals you have should really be written as

$$
\phi(x_i) = 
\int_{-\pi/\epsilon}^{-\pi/L}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-ik_ix^i}\tilde{\phi}(k_i) 
+
\int^{\pi/\epsilon}_{\pi/L}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-ik_ix^i}\tilde{\phi}(k_i)
$$
Usually you take $L\rightarrow \infty$, but that is where the $\pi/\epsilon$ comes from.

The answer to your second question I believe is found here [Does "sum over all paths" in the path integral imply "sum over all paths" in momentum space when one Fourier-transforms?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216769/does-sum-over-all-paths-in-the-path-integral-imply-sum-over-all-paths-in-mom).

Comment: I still don't understand “This lattice spacing brings with it a UV cutoff to all of the fields”. Consider $k=\frac{2\pi n}{L}$, n=1,2,3..., $k$ does have a minimum $\frac{2\pi}{L}$, but why it also have a maximum？@user3166083

Comment: If your fields are on a discrete lattice, then, for example, you know information about two points $\phi(x_i)$ and $\phi(x_i + \epsilon)$, but not, say,  $\phi(x_i + \epsilon/2)$. You cannot get arbitrarily close between two points on a lattice. This means that the fields do not have access to Fourier modes corresponding to distances shorter than the lattice spacing.